# Add color on column with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, composition

How can I add css class on odd columns in a table with jquery?

My code is:

```
$("table columns:odd").addClass("colors");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target `td` tags inside your table, and you have to use `nth-child` with `odd`:

```
$("table td:nth-child(odd)").addClass("colors");
```

You can also do it more simple:

```
$("table td:odd").addClass("colors");
```

Comment: this will work although you can use just `:odd` and `:even` in jquery :)

Comment: true. I will add that option to my answer also. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "table td:odd" ).addClass('colors');
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xj4t19gh/)